# Convert .Net Core Web API & Angular app to Cordova

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-3

I have developed an .net core 2.2 with an Angular 8 application. They both exist in the same project structure. The .net core application acts as an API for the client side Angular 8 application. When I am publishing app it will give me following folder structure:

```
Root Folder (having .net core files)
Root Folder/wwwroot
Root Folder/ClientApp/dist (having angular files)
```

This whole publish folder I am putting into "www" folder where cordova project resides. I changed the "config.xml" of cordova project.

```
<content src="ClientApp/dist/index.html" />
```

When i try to run the app on android, it just showing me "Loading..." message on emulator.

I understand that normal behaviour of .net core application first bootstrap to project dll and then route to angular application. Then how to convert app to android in cordova?

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: No I didn't find any soultion and hence create two different project web api and angular.